# Problems with using the Haar Cascade

Tags: c++, image, algorithm, opencv, computer-vision

I have problems when using Haar Cascade. I'd like to train a Cascade to find certain birds (toucans) in photos. It works if I just cut out toucan with frame and background, but with birds it finds part of the background. If I cut out only the bird with Grab (and fill background with white), the program doesn't work even with original (white) images.

Pictures with a simple background work well (though I'm trying to get it to detect the entire toucan)
[image]

But in a complex background it is terrible:
[image]

A Haar cascade is formed from good and bad images.
Solving the problem in the background of good pictures, I decided to clean the background. Leaving only a bird, and all colored background cut and flooded white. After that, the search program has ceased to find any birds.

1. Haar cascade Standard code opencv (opencv_createsamples.exe)
2. Finding birds on the basis of the cascade:

```cpp
int main(){
    cv::Mat gray = cv::imread("7.jpg", 1); 
    cv::CascadeClassifier cascadeSymbol; 
    bool cascadeSymbolLoad = cascadeSymbol.load("cascade.xml"); 

    if (!cascadeSymbolLoad)
    {
        std::cerr << "Cascade not load. Check your directory \"haarcascade_russian_plate_number_symbol.xml\"" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    std::vector<cv::Rect> symbols;
    cascadeSymbol.detectMultiScale(gray, symbols); 

    for (auto& p : symbols)
    {
        cv::Point symbolBegin = cv::Point(p.x, p.y);
        cv::Point symbolEnd = cv::Point(p.x + p.width, p.y + p.height);

        std::cout << "X: " << p.x << " Y: " << p.y << " Width: " << p.width << " Height: " << p.height << std::endl;
        rectangle(gray, symbolBegin, symbolEnd, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    }
    cv::imshow("Test", gray);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, post your code and some images to help us understand your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I ask the question the first time. Updated.

Comment: From my experience, it appears that you're training your classifier improperly. Do you mind posting the commands that you used when training the classifier?